# Row numbering by group and date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question about numbering rows by group AND by one further condition. I know how to do this by group but not by adding one further condition.

Suppose I have the ID and the DATE and want to create NUM as shown in the table:

**ID** *......*  **DATE***......*  **NUM**
1       20160103  *......* 1 
1       20160104*......* 1
1       20160104*......* 2
1       20160105*......* 1
1       20160105*......* 2
1       20160105*......* 3
1       20160106*......* 1
2       20160103*......* 1
2       20160103*......* 2
2       20160105*......* 1

Any one knows How to do this?

Comment: Thank you Ronak Shah! That what quick!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
 df$NUM <- with(df, ave(ID, ID, DATE, FUN =seq_along))
```